# calculating new columns with NA in starting columns

Tags: r, sum, na, calculated-columns

I have `data.frame(col1 = 1:4, col2 = c(NA,1,2,3), col3 = 5:8)`

[image]

and want to create extra columns which is based on computations involving the other columns with `NA` in it, but keep getting `NA` as a result. I do not want to see NA, but want to see 1, based on `df %>% mutate( new = .[[1]] + .[[2]])`

[image]

Any suggestions how to work through this? I would prefer to stay using tidyverse and dplyr

Comment: do you want `df %>% 
  mutate(new = rowSums(.[1:2], na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: also column differences, `df %>% mutate( new = .[[1]] - .[[2]])`, and `df %>% mutate( new2 = .[[2]] - .[[1]])`

Comment: Well in that case you can replace NAs with zeros

Comment: but then want to show `NA` at the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible framework: `replace` NA with 0s, do your calculations, and then use `rows_update` to replace the original NAs.

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  replace(is.na(.), 0) %>% 
  mutate(new = .[[1]] - .[[2]]) %>% 
  rows_update(df)

  col1 col2 col3 new
1    1   NA    5   1
2    2    1    6   1
3    3    2    7   1
4    4    3    8   1
```

Comment: thanks, never knew about the `rows_update()` function in dplr